# Would these two generate the same compile time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class

I know that @class is suppose to speed up compile time, but if I had a case like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class BNRItem;
@interface BNRItemStore : NSObject
@end
```

---

```
#import "BNRItemStore.h"
#import "BNRItem.h"

@implementation BNRItemStore
@end
```

Could I do this instead and still get the same compile time:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BNRItem.h"
@interface BNRItemStore : NSObject
@end
```

---

```
#import "BNRItemStore.h"

@implementation BNRItemStore
@end
```

Comment: The `@class` is not to speed up compile time but the set an forward declaration for a class. In your example there seems to be no need for the forward declaration of `BNRItem`. You could just use the `#import`

Comment: @rckoenes not sure what point you are making -- when used as a substitute for unnecessary `#import`/`#include`, forward declarations **do** speed up compile times and reduce dependencies. it doesn't make much difference for tiny projects, but can save hours (per day) on very large projects. or from another angle - typical incremental builds can be seconds vs minutes on medium-sized projects. since every objc instance is a pointer, you can achieve very fast compile times on large projects because of low dependency, if structured and maintained correctly.

Comment: True, but the `@class` isn't just there to speedup code and in most cases it will not be necessary.  But you are correct in stating that could speed thing up, although with LLVM if not seen any improvement. But it fix some circle reference in some projects. (which should not have been there, but that's another story)

Comment: @rckoenes yes, forward declarations can serve many purposes; compile times, dependency, circular references, abstraction. it reduces compile times for any C based compiler -- maybe clang's just fast and uses low memory for your projects, and you see no difference? i work on some large projects -- forward declarations make huge differences in medium and larger projects (significant improvements are evident).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(assuming you actually use `BNRItem` someplace in these files)

it would be the same for `BNRItemStore.m`, but it is likely to increase compile times and recompilation frequency for anything that `#import`s `BNRItemStore.h` -- because it's common that many classes that need to see `BNRItemStore` do not need to also see `BNRItem`'s `@interface`.

as that pattern spreads to many headers in your projects, a simple edit to one header can require recompiling a large set of files, with a large set of included files. it also spreads to the indexer, which is continually indexing based on changes.

best to use the forward declarations, unless your project is (and will remain) tiny.

it's actually really nice to be able to declare all your instance variables/properties in the `.m` -- as this is a fairly new addition to clang. abstraction and build times can improve significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

You wouldn't get the SAME at compile time. `@class` just tells the compiler its going to see that class, so treat it as a class (take it out, and you get errors) whereas `#import` tells the compiler to completely import the `.h` (header) file for that class.

So it will be slower (as you've suggested), especially if the `.h` (header) file for the class `#import`s any other files. For an interface you don't need all that functionality, you just need the definition.

But to all intents and purposes the perceived functionality as far as you are concerned is exactly the same, so yes in that respect.